# Making a POST request with an XML file to a REST API

Tags: xml, delphi, post, http-post, multipartform-data

I would like somebody to help me make a `POST` request to a REST API using Delphi.

This is a curl command that works perfectly:

```bash
curl -X 'POST' \
'https://ecf.dgii.gov...ValidarSemilla' \
-H 'accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
-F 'xml=@semilla.xml;type=text/xml'
```

With curl, I'm doing it perfectly, but with Delphi I can't do it. I've tried countless commands, with `TIdHTTP`, with `TRESTClient`, with `THTTPClient`, with `IXMLHTTPRequest`. I do the `GET` well, but the `POST` sending files do not upload, they say the files are invalid.

Can someone give me a hand? I think it is the manipulation of how to say the headers and others.

Comment: All of the components you mentioned are able to send such a POST request, so for you to be having trouble with all of them means you are likely doing something fundamentally wrong, but we can't see what you actually attempted, so we can't tell you what you are doing wrong. Please [edit] your question to show your actual code that is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I make the solution for this by myself searching and it works.

```
procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  response: TStringStream;
  postData: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
  idhttp1: TIdHTTP;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1.PassThrough := True;

  IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.create(nil);
  idhttp1.handleredirects := True;

  with IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1 do
  begin
    SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
    SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];
    SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
    SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 2;
  end;

  with IdHTTP1 do
  begin
    //HTTPOptions:= [hoKeepOrigProtocol];
    ProtocolVersion:=pv1_1;
    IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocket1;
    ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication := False;
    Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36';
    Request.Referer := 'https://ecf.dgii.gov.do/testecf/autenticacion/help/index.html';
    Request.Accept := 'appication/json';
    Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
    HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams];
    Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate, br';
    Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Accept-Language: es-US,es;q=0.9,es-
     419;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,gl;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,pt;q=0.4');
    request.CustomHeaders.Add('Origin: https://ecf.dgii.gov.do');
  end;

  idhttp1.Intercept:=IdLogFile1;
  response := TStringStream.Create(EmptyStr);
  postData := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create();

  try
    postData.AddFile ('xml','D:\Programas\http_delphi\Win32\Debug\xml\semilla.xml', 'text/xml');

    try
      IdHTTP1.Post ('https://ecf.dgii.gov.do/testecf/autenticacion/api/autenticacion/validarsemilla', postdata, response );
      Memo1.Text := response.DataString;
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        ShowMessage(E.Message);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    response.Free();
    postData.Free();
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You don't need the `TStringStream`, as `Post()` has an overload that returns a `string`, eg: `Memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Post('url', postdata);`

Comment: You allright. Thanks A Lot.